# Loops in c# c c++ and java

Tags: c#

why isn't there a do while loop in c#?
 in almost all other languages like c,c++, and java there exist a do while, but not in c#!

Comment: "in almost all other languages like c,c++, and java there exist a do while, but not in c#" are you really sure??

Comment: What made you think there wasn't a do/while loop in C#?

Comment: There IS a do while loop in C#.

Comment: Way to do your research.

Answer (score 12):

There is a do-while loop in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx

The syntax is the same as in other languages you enumerated:

```
do {
  //stuff
} while (condition);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
do {
    // something
} while(condition);
```

et voila

Answer (score 5):

Ummm...last I checked, there is:

[do (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx)

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doh!");
} while(someCondition);
```